# Patter for byte when I got pattern for numbers in lexer

Tags: haskell, lexer, alex

I have pattern for numbers in lexer

```
$digit=0-9
   $digit+                       { \s -> TNum  (readRational s) }
```

I want to add another pattern for bytes. Bytes contain 2 symbols from diaposon 0 - f.
Which pattern I should write for byte?
Will it distinguish 11 :: byte and 11 :: num correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you add two overlapping patterns in your lexer then it will either fail or simply select one of them (I don't know the exact behavior of alex), so that is probably not what you want.

If I understand it correctly there are actually two issues at play here:

1. decimal and hexadecimal numbers overlap
2. fixed-size numeric types overlap, e.g. 11 could be 8 bits or 32 bits.

The common approach to solve problem 1 is to add a prefix to hexadecimal numbers. C uses the prefix `0x` for that. So then 17 would be written as `0x11` in hexadecimal.

I think you should not try to solve problem 2 in the lexer, just keep the numbers as a general number type. Later during type checking you can determine the exact type that is required by the context or default to a type if there are no other constraints.